# Entity Framework object is not null but `== null` returns true

Tags: c#, entity-framework

My code:

```
var x = myEntities.MyTable
                  .Include("MyOtherTable")
                  .Include("MyOtherTable.YetAnotherTable")
                  .SingleOrDefault(c => c.Name == someName);
```

This returns correctly the object that I can view in intellisense within visual studio as being correct.

The next line is:

```
if (x == null)
{
}
```

However this statement returns true and the code inside the `{}` executes. What could cause this?

Edit:

Added this line above the null check:

```
var someName = x.Name;
```

This code works perfectly and someName becomes a `string` with the Name of the object in it.

The `== null` still returns true.

IDE Screenshots:

[image]

[image]

edit: code in a function seems to work:

```
    public void bibble(MyObjectType s)
    {
        if (s == null)
        {

            throw new Exception();
        }
    }
--
    string someName = testVariable.Name;

    this.bibble(testVariable); // Works without exception

    if (testVariable == null)
    {
        // Still throws an exception
        throw new Exception();
    }
```

Now it doesn't evaluate to `true` in the other method, but does in the main method for the same variable. So weird.

Edit: Here's the IL for this section:

```
  IL_0037:  callvirt   instance string [MyLibrary]MyLibrary.MyCompany.MyObjectType::get_Name()
  IL_003c:  stloc.3
  IL_003d:  ldarg.0
  IL_003e:  ldloc.2
  IL_003f:  call       instance void MyOtherLibrary.ThisClass::bibble(class [MyLibrary]MyLibrary.MyCompany.MyObjectType)
  IL_0044:  nop
  IL_0045:  ldloc.2
  IL_0046:  ldnull
  IL_0047:  ceq
  IL_0049:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_004a:  ceq
  IL_004c:  stloc.s    CS$4$0001
  IL_004e:  ldloc.s    CS$4$0001
  IL_0050:  brtrue.s   IL_0059
  IL_0052:  nop
  IL_0053:  newobj     instance void [mscorlib]System.Exception::.ctor()
  IL_0058:  throw
```

Edit: Even MORE bizarre is this:

```
var myEFObjectIsNull = testVariable == null;

// Intellisense shows this value as being FALSE.

if (myEFObjectIsNull)
{
    // This code is ran. What.
    throw FaultManager.GetFault();
}
```

Comment: Updated question. So bizarre!

Comment: Are you certain you don't have a semicolon after the `if`?

Comment: You could also try `if (object.ReferenceEquals(x, null))`

Comment: I will ask you for doble check, maybe you have a line like if (x=null)  with single '=' ?

Comment: Have checked, the code is definitely `== null`, there is nothing else with the same variable name, I have also removed the `.Include`s and same issue.

Comment: @celerno that would throw a compiler error unless `x` is a `bool`.

Comment: Can you run it in the debugger and "step into" the `if` statement?

Comment: at this point, having eliminated the obvious, I'm half inclined to think "compiler bug" (it does happen occasionally). Could you please try pulling everything after `var x = ...` into a separate method, i.e. `var x = ...; AnotherMethod(x);`, with your `if(x==null)` etc in `AnotherMethod` ?

Comment: Can you close and restart visual studio. Then run w/out the debugger and then attach to that code? Perhaps the debugger or VS is breaking everything as it tends to do on Mondays.

Comment: Oooh. I put the check into another method and now it correctly returns `false` for the comparison

Comment: @SLC if you can still repro it by moving the code back to how it was, I would be very interested in the IL of the failing code. If we can prove it is a compiler bug, we should ensure it gets logged. Are you familiar with extracting the IL?

Comment: @D Stanley i know, but it's a "var", and at the time when I asked, it didn't had that much of the background. Still looking for the solution, its a good question with good comments (excluding mine, of course)

Comment: I've added the IL, does that mean anything to you? I don't know much about IL :0

Answer (score 5):

This can happen if you have added a custom `==` operator overload, and made a mess of it. The overload will prefer a `==(MyTable,MyTable)` overload, and will choose that when comparing to `null`:

```
static class Program {
    static void Main() {
        Foo x = new Foo();
        if(x==null) {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Eek");
        }
    }
}

public class Foo {
    public static bool operator ==(Foo x,Foo y) {
        return true; // or something more subtle...
    }

    public static bool operator !=(Foo x, Foo y) {
        return !(x==y);
    }
}
```

Comment: Makes sense, but I haven't done this. Perhaps EF has some kind of bug or bizarre feature built into it that is causing this?

Comment: @SLC simple way to find out: change it to: `if(((object)x)==null)` - if it works correctly, then the issue is almost certainly an operator overload. You can also just put the caret on the `==` and press `F12`, IIRC. That will take you to the operator definition that it intends to use.

Comment: you have a point, but it sounds pretty rare he had this code somewhere.

Comment: @celerno I'm open to other suggestions of what can cause `==null` to report incorrectly; I know this one *can* do it.

Comment: The above comparison also evaluates to `true` and it executes the code within the braces.

Comment: @SLC the cast to `object` still enters the braces? Hmmm... then it isn't an operator overload. Dammit; it was worth a shot, at least. Are you sure you have built? and don't have any stray `;` as already suggested by D Stanley?

Comment: Nothing unusual I can see, it's using the correct definition. I've just updated the EF model in case that was it, no change there.